# How to redirect incoming connections using iptables and keep client's IP

Tags: ip, mask, iptables

So I have a home server and i'd like to keep my IP masked to prevent DoS attacks and other security issues.

I'm using a VPS running Ubuntu to transfer traffic like this: Client -> VPS -> Home Server

But there's a problem. Everything works fine except everyone that connects to the home server has the same IP address as the VPS. I'd like each client to retain their own IP so they can be uniquely identified. How would I go about doing this? Currently using the following commands:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination myIP:80
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Theres probably a million other questions on this, but I don't know what to search to find them.